# Eclipse error : Unable to find resources

Tags: eclipse, certification

I am trying to refresh from server a force.com project in eclipse. But it throws the error : Unable to fetch resources. unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
The same happens when I am trying to create a new project

Comment: Are you using some kind of proxy to access the Internet?

Comment: No i am  not . In fact it was working fine, all of a sudden this error started showing up

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and re installing jre and then closing and opening eclipse worked for me.